# How to track type-ahead internal search in SiteCatalyst

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm planning out how to track internal search data in Omniture/SiteCatalyst.

It's a fairly straight-forward plan for a standard "enter a term and get a page of results" model: set sProps and eVars with the terms, the count of results, and the page searched from, then fire a success event for searching and another for clicking a search result.

For a type-ahead search--where the user is given search results as they type in a search bar--what's a good strategy for handling the timing of event submissions so that you don't end up with different events/entries for letters 4, 5, 6, and 7 of a search term's entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our solution was to leverage a delay on the autocomplete to reduce the number of calls. From a tracking standpoint, if someone pauses for 1 second (or 500 ms, whatever), then they're probably actually waiting for the autocomplete results, and that constitutes a valid search.

From a technical standpoint, we leveraged the [`delay` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay) on the jQuery UI widget.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy I've always used is to not track the "auto-complete" search features..put the tracking on the search results page same as normal.  Or are you saying the whole search results page is being output as the user types?  If that is the case...one thing you could do is write some code to pop the Omniture code when the search field loses focus.

Another thing you can do is as the visitor is typing in the search bar, on each keypress, write the current value to a cookie. Then have some code that runs on page load to look for that cookie and if it exists, pop the Omniture search variables and erase the cookie. Alternatively you can keep track of current value w/ a server-side session variable since I assume this thing is ajax driven, and output the omn code w/ server-side code if session var exists. These methods would mean that the search events and vars would not pop on the search results page...this probably isn't that big a deal, unless you have supporting variables you pop, like an "internal search referrer" prop/eVar that keeps track of the previous page the visitor was on (or the page the visitor was on when they performed the search). So you'll have to keep that in mind and carry that over as well.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a search you might be aware of the concept that query string parameter get added at the end of URL.

Suppose www.stackoverfow.com is website and when are you performing a search on it then it will be like **www.stackoverflow.com?q=yourname** , yourname is the searchkeyword.This keyword we can capture in sitecatalyst.

you can see google.com while searching on internet for sitecatalyst is --- 
**www.google.co.in/search?q=sitecatalyst**

In the same way we can use query string parameter as q = something.

---

after doing all this thing we can use the plugin getQueryParam in plugin section of the s_code library file to fetch that variable and store that in sitecatalyst variable...

example:-

```js
function s_doPlugins(s) {
var one = s.getQueryParam("q");
if(one)
s.eVar1=one;
}
s.doPlugins=s_doPlugins
```

insert this below code outside plugin section

```js
/*
* Returns the value of a specified query string parameter, if found in the current page URL.
*/
s.getQueryParam=new Function("p","d","u",""
+"var s=this,v='',i,t;d=d?d:'';u=u?u:(s.pageURL?s.pageURL:s.wd.locati"
+"on);if(u=='f')u=s.gtfs().location;while(p){i=p.indexOf(',');i=i<0?p"
+".length:i;t=s.p_gpv(p.substring(0,i),u+'');if(t){t=t.indexOf('#')>-"
+"1?t.substring(0,t.indexOf('#')):t;}if(t)v+=v?d+t:t;p=p.substring(i="
+"=p.length?i:i+1)}return v");
s.p_gpv=new Function("k","u",""
+"var s=this,v='',i=u.indexOf('?'),q;if(k&&i>-1){q=u.substring(i+1);v"
+"=s.pt(q,'&','p_gvf',k)}return v");
s.p_gvf=new Function("t","k",""
+"if(t){var s=this,i=t.indexOf('='),p=i<0?t:t.substring(0,i),v=i<0?'T"
+"rue':t.substring(i+1);if(p.toLowerCase()==k.toLowerCase())return s."
+"epa(v)}return ''");
```

you will find that it will capture your search results

please let me know in case of more clarifications